# QT/C++ QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded on OS X

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qsqldatabase

I'm using
OS X: 10.12.4
Qt Creator 4.0.2
MySQL 5.0.12 (looks like that, not sure)
C++

Under from QT I am trying to connect to a mysql database by following code:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("sql104.rf.gd"); // 185.27.134.10
//db.setPort(3306);
db.setUserName("correctname");
db.setPassword("correctpw");
db.setDatabaseName("rfgd_19926673_shop");

if (db.open()){
   ui->label->setText("success");
   } else {
   i->label->setText("fail");
}
```

And it fails with

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

I've tried this with no result

```
QPluginLoader loader;
loader.setFileName("/Users/Ivan/Qt/5.7/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib");
```

It returns

```
Cannot load library 
/Users/Ivan/Qt/5.7/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib: (dlopen(/Users/Ivan/Qt/5.7/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib, 5): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/mysql55/mysql/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/Ivan/Qt/5.7/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib
Reason: image not found)
/Users/Ivan/build-CourierHelperDesktop-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_clang_64bit-Release/CourierHelperDesktop.app/Contents/MacOS
```

I've got only

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/lib/lib/mysqlclient.20.dylib
```

Have tried

```
mkdir /opt/local/lib/mysql55/mysql/
cp /usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/lib/lib/mysqlclient.20.dylib /opt/local/lib/mysql55/mysql
```

No help.

Please, somebody, help me out. I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem on macOS High Sierra (10.13.4) with:

- mysql-5.6.40-macos10.13-x86_64.dmg
- mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-macos10.12-x86_64.dmg
- Qt 5.10.1
- clang: Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0

You were lucky, I didn't get this message at first. I had to enabled more debugging info by setting a new environment variable called `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` as `1` on **Project Properties > Run**. Executing my application again revealed pretty much the same error message as yours.

To solve the problem, the first thing you need to do is find where `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` is located in the computer:

```
$ find / -iname libmysqlclient.18.dylib
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Great, now find where Qt stores its plugins:

```
$ qmake -query QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS
/Users/karlphillip/Qt/5.10.1/clang_64/plugins
```

and create a new environment variable on your Terminal with this information to make the next part easier:

```
$ export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=`qmake -query QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS`
```

Finally, go to the `sqldrivers` inside Qt plugins directory and update the shared library path with the information you found earlier:

```
$ cd /Users/karlphillip/Qt/5.10.1/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers
$ install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib $QT_PLUGIN_PATH/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib
```

Done.